# How to tell if a UITextField is firstResponder

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitextfield

I'm working on an app that has a signup feature.  The signup process is broken up into 3 different views, each of which has 2 UITextField to take user input.  I have also implemented the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods;

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

and

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Depending on which `UITextField` is in focus will determine what method is called when the user taps the return key on the keyboard.  I would like to just call my `resignFirstResponder` method for the first 4 `UITextField`s but on the last textField I would like to call my join method when return is pressed.

So my question is; How can I determine which `UITextField` just called the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method?

As always, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
   if (textField == theLastTextField) {
      //joinmethod
   } else {
      [textField resignFirstResponder];
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the speedy response!  I like the simple solution here but I would still like to know how to tell which textfield is in focus or which textfield called the textFieldShouldReturn: method.

Comment: I just setup condition if([textField isFirstResponder])  will work perfect.  thanks again!